# How to get a default zero double value in PHP?

Tags: php, double

My question sounds simple, but the solution seems to be hard/tricky:

```
var_dump(0.0);
```

returns me

```
float 0
```

But why? Also the tries with `doubleval` or a double cast doesn´t solve the problem. I need this for setting a default value to a double table column in the database to zero through mysql pdo driver.

Comment: What?  That is float `0` but doesn't display the unnecessary `.0`  If your DB column is double then sending string, int or float 0 will result in the same value in the DB.  What is the actual problem that you are seeing?

Comment: Upvoter, care to explain?

Comment: `0` is equivalent to `0.0` is equivalent to `000000.00000000`. They all represent the exact same value, there's no problem here. What do you *think* is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, doubles and [floats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) are the same thing in PHP.

Have you tried inserting `0.0` into that table and gotten an error?